# Methods of reading in and creating a list/array with excel information from excel

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, input, data-manipulation

Imagine I am given two columns: a,b,c,d,e,f and e,f,g,h,i,j (commas indicating a new row in the column)

How could I read in such information from excel and put it in an two separate arrays? I would like to manipulate this info and read it off later. as part of an output.

Comment: In excel you open VBA and you make your variable equal to the range of the columns you want.  See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549191/array-from-range-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @ForwardEd I think he want's a python solution.

Comment: @lismUK quite possible, but not stated, and the question was tagged with excel.

Comment: @ForwardEd Two of the other tags are python though.

Comment: @LismUK Yes they are, but again the question does not rule out the possibility of VBA within excel.  Python is a very educated guess, but not the sole possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices here.  If your data is rectangular, starts from A1, etc. you should just use [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/excel/file", sheetname = "My Sheet Name")
print(df["column1"].values)
print(df["column2"].values)
```

If your data is a little messier, and the read_excel options aren't enough to get your data, then I think your only choice will be to use something a little lower level like the fantastic [xlrd module](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) (read the quickstart on the README)